# Should I split a table into 2 separate tables?

Tags: sql

I'm very new to  SQL and I'm trying to learn it by working on a small personal project. I have a table of
`users` like this:

```
  Table users{
  id int [pk, increment] 
  username varchar(14) [not null, unique]
  username_lower_case varchar (14) [not null, unique]
  email varchar(40) [not null, unique]
  password varchar(72) [not null]
  admin boolean [not null]
  bio text [default: 'No info ']
  banned boolean [not null]
  banned_by id 
  banned_reason varchar
  active_account boolean [not null]
  created_at timestamp [not null]
}
```

I'm debating if `banned, banned_by, banned_reason` should be extracted into a different table or it is ok to have current structure.  I fill like it's easier to leave as is because later on I don't need to join tables to get data, however, my understanding might be completely wrong. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: I assume that a user can be banned multiple times and that you'd want to maintain a history of bans of a user... in which case the _multiplicity_ of bans-to-users is not `1:1` but is `m:1` which means that you should store ban information in a separate table.

Comment: @Dai Thank you, no if a user is banned it's forever.

Comment: What if a ban is abrogated? Or it turns out a moderator was on a power-trip? A huge mistake when doing data-modelling (i.e. when designing a database) is to assume something is unchanging or immutable, or unique, and so on. I feel your design is wrong.

Comment: @Dai I understand what you mean, however, if I don't care about history of bans, is it viable?

Comment: Well... yes. But just because something works doesn't mean it can't be improved.

Comment: I see `password varchar(72)` - I hope you're not storing passwords in plaintext. You should be storing password digests in a `binary` column.

Comment: @Dai thank you very much, I'll try to think about it and rework it.

Comment: @Dai no password is going to be `bcrypted`

Comment: If this is SQL Server, you should not be using the `text` data-type: it's deprecated, stored off-table (so it's _slow_), and doesn't support Unicode. You should use `nvarchar(4000)` - only use `nvarchar(max)` if you're absolutely sure you need more than 4000 characters of space - and even then, add a `LEN` check constraint to prevent denial-of-service attacks from the insertion of excessively large values.

Comment: @Dai it's going to be Postgres. Thanks.

Comment: @Dai I'm sorry, I'm trying to understand how to implement it better. So, is it ok if I keep `banned boolean` in the user table, and create a separate table to maintain history of bans where I store  `banned_by, banned_reason`  and other ban-related data?  Or should `banned boolean` be with this separate table too?  In my design I'm planning to check if a user is banned on each server request, therefore I was thinking it would be a good idea to keep it in users table.  Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are referring to is normalization in databases. The goal of normalisation at a very basic level is to take what is redundant and repeated data and have a reference to it to save on writes and storage. You can read more on that here [database-normalization](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-database-normalization-in-sql-server/).

Typically this is a rule that can be broken for business reasons or ease of use especially in reporting however it's best to understand the rules before breaking them. I have worked on large datasets where it was not normalised (denormalised) to make life easier when querying however this approach is not as efficient in writes as there is now redundant data.

I personally would have a separate table for bans as it's enough to be a distinct entity in your model and if it remains one complete table you would have a lot of superfluous data thus making scalability a potential issue. For example you may implement a new feature on bans which would be easier if it was it's own table.

Ultimately it depends on the logic and the needs of your application and what you'll be doing with the data. The best bet for learning or an application where the future use of data is unknown in my opinion is to implement a 3rd Normal Form database or beyond.

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistakes now.

Comment: For "ease of querying" don't denormalize. Instead create materialized views (aka "indexed views") and query those.

Comment: Some good responses on when to denormalise can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/when-should-you-denormalize).